# Inversing slider value without affecting drag functionality MUI Slider React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a MUI slider where the value of the slider needs to be inverted based on a boolean variable. My current code inverts it correctly but it also inverts the drag functionality, meaning if I tried to drag my slider towards 0, it would move towards 100 instead. I can't think of a workaround to correct this. Would appreciate if anyone has any suggestions I could try.

```
const handleSelectionChange = (e: any) => {
  if (typeof e.target.value === 'string') {
    onChange(e.target.value)
  } else {
    onChange(Number(e.target.value))
  }
}
<Slider
            aria-label='DiceRoll'
            defaultValue={50}
            valueLabelDisplay='auto'
            step={1}
            min={0}
            max={100}
            value={overUnder ? 100 - targetNumber : targetNumber} //overUnder is boolean and targetNumber ranges from 0 to 100.
            marks={marks}
            onChange={handleSelectionChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few hours I've found the solution, it's actually a pretty simple solution, just an additional 3 lines of codes. We just have to introduce another state which only purpose is to display the correct slider Value.

```
const handleSelectionChange = (e: any) => {
  if(overUnder){ //defaultValue of overUnder is true
    if (typeof e.target.value === 'string') {
      onChange(e.target.value)
    } else {
      onChange(Number(e.target.value))
    }
  } else {
    if (typeof e.target.value === 'string') {
      onChange(100 - e.target.value)
      setFlippedTargetNumber(e.target.value)
    } else {
      onChange(100 - Number(e.target.value))
      setFlippedTargetNumber(Number(e.target.value))
    }
  }
}

const [ flippedTargetNumber, setFlippedTargetNumber] = useState<number>(50)

<Slider
        aria-label='DiceRoll'
        defaultValue={50}
        valueLabelDisplay='auto'
        step={1}
        min={0}
        max={100}
        value={overUnder ? targetNumber : flippedTargetNumber} //overUnder is boolean and targetNumber ranges from 0 to 100.
        marks={marks}
        onChange={handleSelectionChange}
/>
```

basically what this does is, when overUnder = true, and when it's true, the slider would just work normally. when it is flipped and overUnder = false, onChange will update targetNumber to inverse [which is needed for other components]. and setFlippedTargetNumber will be used as slider Value instead of targetNumber.

Hope this helps anyone who is facing  a similar problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `valueLabelFormat` function, you can simply format the number display instead of the number value itself, preventing the problem.

Use this instead:

`valueLabelFormat={(v) => (overUnder ? 100 - v : v)}`

Set the value back to normal:

`value={targetNumber}`

```js
const { StrictMode, useState } = React;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;

const App = () => {

  const [overUnder, setOverUnder] = useState(false);
  const [targetNumber, setTargetNumber] = useState(42.0);
  
  const handleSelectionChange = (e) => {
    if (typeof e.target.value === "string") {
      setTargetNumber(e.target.value);
    } else {
      setTargetNumber(Number(e.target.value));
    }
  };
  
  const onFlip = () => {
    setOverUnder((s) => !s);
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={onFlip}>Flip</button>
      </div>
      <div>Target Number: {targetNumber}</div>
      <div>Over Under: {`${overUnder}`}</div>
      <MaterialUI.Slider
        aria-label="DiceRoll"
        defaultValue={50}
        valueLabelDisplay="on"
        step={1}
        min={0}
        max={100}
        value={targetNumber}
        valueLabelFormat={(v) => (overUnder ? 100 - v : v)}
        marks={false}
        inverted={true}
        onChange={handleSelectionChange}
        sx={{ pt: "10rem" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@latest/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
```

Also a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mui-inverted-slider-dbio8h) for reference.

Comment: Hey Wesley, very interesting solution, but this isn't quite exactly what I am looking for. In a sense I need the slider to work just like this https://stake.com/casino/games/dice. The slider's own value changes and is still draggable to the right direction. Currently the valueLabelFormat only shows the label popping up.